# Does GitHub Actions have an equivalent concept to Azure Pipeline's custom build number syntax?

Tags: azure-pipelines, github-actions

I have a project that is using .NET Arcade's version number algorithm. This algorithm relies on Azure Pipelines providing a `Build.BuildNumber` variable in the format `yyyyMMdd.r`, where `yyyyMMdd` is, of course, the date of the build, and `r` is an incrementing integer unique to the day. For example, a series of build numbers may look like this:

```
20211015.1
20211015.2
20211016.1
20211016.2
20211016.3
20211017.1
```

I took a look at the [GitHub Actions environment variable docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) but unfortunately it does not seem that either of these pieces of semantic data are available.

Am I missing something? Is there another way to accomplish what I want? I'd hate to throw away this excellent versioning algorithm.

Comment: I have been searching for the exact same thing for almost a year. I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has introduced new environment variables, GITHUB_RUN_ID and GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER which are unique numbers for each workflow run, so you're probably better off using those than this GitHub action.  See https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Comment: `GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER` doesn't work the same way as Azure DevOps `$(Rev.r)`.  It doesn't reset each day :(. It just increments by one each time the workflow runs.